# How to set default constraint to UTC_DATE on a mysql column

Tags: mysql

I am not able to create default constraint to my table.

```
ALTER TABLE `learning`.`person_shift_tbl` 
CHANGE COLUMN `StartDate` `StartDate` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT UTC_DATE();
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UTC_DATE()' at line 2

Comment: Afaik the only way to do that is with a trigger.

Comment: Just wondering what's the reason? Why it can't be set.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support dynamic default values, the only exceptions are CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and AUTO_INCREMENT.